# Bokeh sticky crosshair

Tags: python, bokeh

In [Bokeh](http://bokeh.org/), is there a tool similar to [spike lines in plotly](https://plotly.com/python/hover-text-and-formatting/#spike-lines) ?
The crosshair tool is close to that but is it possible to make it stick to a plot?

Answer (score 1):

I am not aware of an implemented sticky tool in `bokeh` but it is possible to prototype it using the `HoverTool` and `CustomJS`.

The code below needs some explanation.

1. I set ranges to the axis to get `p.x_range.start` and `p.y_range.start`. These don't exist by default.
2. I have to collect the renderers per color to register the to the correct callback. If there are multiple colors, I have to add multiple HoverTools
3. At the moment the JS Code asks for the correct name `a` of the data source. This can be improved.

#### Minimal example

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, CustomJS, HoverTool

source = ColumnDataSource(dict(a=[1,2,3,4,5], x=[1,2,3,4,5]))

p = figure(x_range=(0.9,5.1), y_range=(0.9,5.1))

p.line('a', 'x', source=source, color='red')
cr = p.circle('a', 'x', source=source, color='red')

extra_source = ColumnDataSource({'x0': [], 'y0': [], 'x1': [], 'y1': []})
sb = p.segment(
    x0='x0',
    y0='y0',
    x1='x1',
    y1='y1',
    color='red',
    alpha=0.6,
    line_width=2,
    line_dash="dashed",
    source=extra_source
)

# add a hover tool that sets the link data for a hovered circle
code = """
const data = {'x0': [],'y0': [],'x1': [],'y1': []}
const indices = cb_data.index.indices
console.log(cb_data)
for (let i of indices) {
    // horizontal dashed line
    data['x0'].push(p.x_range.start)
    data['y0'].push(circle.data.a[i])
    data['x1'].push(circle.data.x[i])
    data['y1'].push(circle.data.a[i])

    // vertical dashed line
    data['x0'].push(circle.data.x[i])
    data['y0'].push(p.y_range.start)
    data['x1'].push(circle.data.x[i])
    data['y1'].push(circle.data.a[i])
}
segment.data = data
"""

callback = CustomJS(args={'circle': cr.data_source, 'segment': sb.data_source, 'p':p}, code=code)
p.add_tools(HoverTool(tooltips=None, callback=callback, renderers=[cr]))

show(p)
```

#### Output

[image: sticky tool]